# NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIPrefBranch.getCharPref]"

Tags: imacros

Imacros is showing this error

```
NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff 
(NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIPrefBranch.getCharPref]
```

Please help !!!

I am running this code :

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX

TAB T=1

SET !DATASOURCE livefile.csv

SET !LOOP 2

SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

URL GOTO= "xyz.com"

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=Name:name CONTENT={{!COL1}}

TAG POS=3 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=STYLE:

WAIT SECONDS=5

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Edit

WAIT SECONDS=5

TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:product_edit_form ATTR=ID:description CONTENT=

TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:product_edit_form ATTR=ID:description CONTENT={{!COL2}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=Class:content-header

TAG POS=5 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=STYLE:

WAIT SECONDS=5
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem on previously working imacros macro files. I noticed that if I record a new macro it works fine. The difference between the old macro and the newly recorded one is that the new macro file is a UTF8 file prefixed with Byte Order Mark.

Augmenting @Thomas'answer: By only changing the macro file format from ANSI to UTF8 alone does not work -- the new file must also have a unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM) as well. For UTF8 it is the sequence 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF (see wikipedia entry for Byte Order Mark).

Be sure to use an editor that preserves the BOM. For PSPad, you might have to turn on an option in Program Settings/Program Part 2 to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

There is an invalid/unsupported character in your CSV, maybe an accent letter (À), this online tool can remove them - 
http://textmechanic.co/Remove-Letter-Accents.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by opening the macro in a texteditor and then I changed the encoding of the macro from ANSI to UTF8 and it worked fine again...

Answer (score 1):

In my experience I have to open the .csv file (not the macro) in an application like Notepad++ and then convert the encoding to UFT-8.

In my case the csv file was generated by Excel, and it was encoded using ANSI.

Answer (score 1):

same here - In my case the csv file was generated by Excel, and it was encoded using ANSI. Just open in notepad and save as UTF8

Answer (score 0):

Since I was having no luck with UTF encoding, 
I solved following this approach:

1. Record your macro sample (Rec tab)
2. Open #current.iim
3. Edit at will
4. Save as this_is_my_custom_macro.iim
5. Run this_is_my_custom_macro.iim